# PrimeFaces p:graphicImage support for Streamed Content SVG

Tags: jsf, primefaces, graphicimage

I'm trying to use a p:graphicImage with an SVG in a streamed content.
Right now I'm stuck 'cause if I set the entire path of the file, I'm able to see the image.
If I use the StreamedContent (org.primefaces.model.StreamedContent) and I'll watch inside the Console source, I'm not able to see anything.

```
<p:graphicImage id="imgExpo_#{idPrefix}" value="#{bck.streamedImage}" cache="false" stream="true" > 

public StreamedContent getStreamedImage() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
        
        return defaultEmpty;
    }
    else {
        image =  new DefaultStreamedContent(BckUtils.getImageManager.getImageStream(context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap() , user));
        return image;
    }
}
```

Anyone with some suggestions?

Thanks, Riccardo.

Primefaces 7.0

Comment: Its probably your mime-type is wrong that it doesn't think its an SVG when streaming it?

Comment: Hi @Melloware  thank you for the responde. My mime type is correct and insert inside the web.xml, that's the code line     
 <mime-mapping>
    <extension>svg</extension>
    <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>    
  Any other suggestions? Thank you :D